# OpenGL Extensions: How to use them under OS X -- OpenGL newbie

Tags: macos, opengl

Can anybody point me in a direction to a great tutorial or how-to for using OpenGL Extensions using OS X. I'm learning OpenGL and somewhat of a newbie. I'm using a textbook to learn graphics but it doesn't give platform specific instructions on how to get the code to work.

I'm running OS X(10.6.7) on a MacBookPro with a NVidia GeForce 9400M. I have XCode installed, so I have the necessary headers and libraries to compile and run graphics code. I'm attempting to use the OpenGL extensions and now I'm stuck. Here's my problem:

An example in my textbook utilizes a function called glGenVertexArrays. I see in glext.h that there is a function called glGenVertexArrays, a APIENTRYP next to it, and a typedef slightly below it:

```
wdyn-n233-240-235:GL marklagatuz$ cat glext.h | grep glGenVertexArrays
GLAPI void APIENTRY glGenVertexArrays (GLsizei, GLuint *);
GLAPI void APIENTRY glGenVertexArraysAPPLE (GLsizei, GLuint *);

typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLGENVERTEXARRAYSPROC) (GLsizei n, GLuint *arrays);
```

My question is how to utilize this function in my .cpp source code? I've perused the net, and haven't found great documentation. Maybe cause I'm new to this. Could somebody point me into some great help and tutorials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make your life simple, don't bother with `glext.h` but use a extension wrapper instead. I recommend GLEW, http://glew.sourceforge.net

Comment: Hi. I've now installed GLEW on my system. Additionally, I've glanced through the header file, glew.h, and read the basic and advanced. I'm still unsure how to utilize the extensions in my program. Suppose I want to create a vertex array object. How do utilize this in my code. I'm unsure the syntax, what needs to be declared, etc ... Could you help a newbie? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first thing to do if you want to use GLEW is calling glewInit(); from the thread you created your OpengGL context in, right after the context has been created. Then you should check if the desired extensions are actually available on your system, GLEW provides a very convenient way for this: http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html for how to use vertex buffer objects read this articles http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object